# Run Personalised Pagerank on rating dataset (network x)

Tags: python, networkx, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, pagerank

I have a user-movie rating matrix of this form:

```
movie_id  1     2     3     4     5     ...  1676  1677  1678  1681  1682
user_id                                 ...                              
1683       1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0  ...   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN
1684       1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1685       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1686       NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN  ...   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1687       1.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN
```

i am then running the nx.pagerank method on a nx graph i have created according to the matrix above.
I have already splited my data into a train and test set. But, i can only run the algorithm without a peronalisation factor for my users in order to support a collaborative filtering approach. My question is can i achieve that through the personalisation parameter provided by the networkx method?

```
pagerank_scores_train = nx.pagerank(G=B,alpha= 0.85,`personalization= some_dictionary_of_node_weights`, max_iter=100, tol=1e-06, nstart=None, weight='weight', dangling=None)
```

Any different approach on the subject of using PPR for collaboratice filtering is welcome...